# The password is invalid or user does not have a password firebase google login

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have problem in login with google, signup is working fine and also got user in firebase console. The problem is when i am trying to login with google account which registered before but I got following error. "The password is invalid or user does not have a password firebase".

```
RoundButton(title: "LogIn", onPress: () async {
                          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                          if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            setState(() {
                              showSpinner = true;
                            });
                            try {
                              final user = await _auth
                                  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: email.toString().trim(),
                                  password: password.toString().trim());
                              if (user != null) {
                                toastedMessages("LogedIn");
                                setState(() {
                                  showSpinner = false;
                                });
                                await Navigator.push(context,
                                    PageTransition(child: HomePage1(),
                                        type: PageTransitionType
                                            .rightToLeftJoined,
                                        childCurrent: widget,
                                        reverseDuration: Duration(
                                            milliseconds: 350),
                                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350)
                                    ));
                              }
                            } catch (e) {
                              toastedMessages(e.toString());
                              setState(() {
                                showSpinner = false;
                              });
                            }
                          }
                        }),
```

Comment: Hi, did run your application in debug mode and checked if email and password are really filled with the correct data? Just to make sure it is not nil or an empty string.

Comment: yes, my app in debug mode, in validator of text field i have set ..if not null then accept values other wise show error